# How to get csv file from azure blob and ingest endpoint into Azure Event Hub using logic app?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-eventhub, azure-eventgrid

I have many CSV file stored in Azure blob storage container, I need those file from azure blob storage and dump into azure event hub using azure logic app.

Scenarios:

1. If any new CSV file is added into the storage container only that new file should be fetched from the blob and pushed to the event hub.
2. If any old file is updated only those files and the newly added files should be fetched from the blob storage by using Azure Logic App.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to my logic app:

You can use [When a blob is added or modified (properties only)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/azureblob/#when-a-blob-is-added-or-modified-(properties-only)) as trigger.

[image]

Then use [Get blob content](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/azureblob/#get-blob-content) to get content of your blob, within `for each`, you need to use [send event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-azure-event-hubs#add-event-hubs-action).

[image]

The detail of `send event 2`:

[image]

Comment: frank,
i have tried the scenario but it give me this error in for each loop,

ExpressionEvaluationFailed. The execution of template action 'For_each' failed: the result of the evaluation of 'foreach' expression '@triggerBody()' is of type 'Object'. The result must be a valid array.

Comment: Please click the `···` button in the upper right corner of the `When a blob is added or modified (properties only)` trigger, then select `settings`, and then turn off `Split On`.

Comment: Does this solve your problem? If you have any questions, you can tell me.